# Code metrics options for a Windows Store application written in Javascript/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps, winjs

Are there any good code metrics options for a Windows Store application written in Javascript/HTML5?

I've rewritten a good portion of a project that a contractor did for us, and I'd like to see how many redundant functions I removed, lines of code deleted, etc.  Microsoft says that its built-in Visual Studio tools don't work with Winjs-based projects, and I can't seem to find any third party tools.

Thanks, all.

Here's the link where MS states JS isn't supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441471.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I use [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) in all my JavaScript projects(windows store apps included) as code quality tool.
It works pretty well and catches most of commonly made errors/bad practices.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but helpful.  Thanks for your post.